# Powershell - set up data removal with retention

Tags: powershell, rotation, backup, retention

I need a PS script that would delete all the subfolders of a directory except for those:

- everything from last 7 days
- one newest folder from every week from past month
- one newest folder from every month from past year

I am fairly new to PS and spent quite some time struggling already. Hate crying for help, but I suppose, this is the right moment.

Thank you!

Comment: Add to question: What version powershell? What is path to "everything from last 7 days"?

Comment: Edited the question a bit. 

Each subfolder contains a unit of data I am trying to back up. I need to keep subfolders in aforementioned retention and delete the others. 

powershell v.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done now (:

```
# Initiate the intervals in days by which the folders will be kept
$savedays = @('7', '14', '21', '30', '60', '90', '120', '150', '180', '210', '240', '270', '300', '330', '360')

# initiate array of folders to be deleted
$killlist = @()

# Start a for loop until hitting the one before last element of $savedays
For ($i=0;$i -lt ($savedays.Length -1 ); $i++) {

    # Get list of folders in the $path_main
    $killlist += @(Get-ChildItem $path_main |
        # Newest first
        Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | 
        # Between one and next elevement of #savedays, i.e. between 7 days ago and 14 days ago
        Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$savedays[$i]) -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-$savedays[$i+1])} |
        # Exclude the most recent folder from the aforementioned period
        Select-Object -Skip 1
        ) 

}

# delete folders
foreach ($folder in $killlist) {
    # delete the folder including contents
    Remove-Item $folder.fullname –recurse
}
```